# How to Add iOS 6.0 Simulator in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i want to add iOS 6.0 Simulator in Xcode 5 for that i add SDK in my Xcode 5 Content Folder From Xcode 4.5 like as

```
Xcode 4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDK/iPhoneOS6.0SDKs/
```

And Copy this SDK Folder in Xcode 5 Folder as

```
Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDK/iPhoneOSSDKs
```

folder but it is not Display iOS 6.0 In my Xcode 5 Simulator.

> Here i not want to Download so please Give me Solution With out
>   Download Option.

Answer (score -1):

Copying **SDK** is just gives a support to that simulator but to view iOS 6.0 simulator in a list (simulator interface), You must have to download it.

Of course it will work for the older OS SDKs, I mean copying older SDKs from older Xcode to newer Xcode SDKs will give you support to create build for older iOS version and it will also supports older OS version APIs, *but it will not work for Simulator as you expected.*

Try to understand that to copy sdks from Xcode 4.5 will not work for new APIs. This can not be the way you are trying to do.

You must have to follow the regular download way!!

Click on Xcode **preferences** >> Go to **Downloads** section

[image]

Download simulator from **Components** section.

Comment: i mention in Question i not want to Download You Show that.With out Download any Solution is Possible? then Give me.

Comment: Check edited answer. Your approach will not support because you need an interface which can support with latest Xcode.

Comment: Okh i will try it and Then Give you response.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Downloads

From there you can download iOS 6 simulator.[image]